# How to include a object when it doesn't include a field from a select() call

Tags: jq

I want to list a couple fields from a JSON structure, including an optional one, that is potentially in an array with other fields I don't want to display. I've been using select() to get the one value from the array I want, but if I have an object that doesn't have that optional key, it is skipped all together. Let me show an example. Here's the data:

```
[
{"field1":"1", "field2":"x", "Tags":[{"Key": "Name", "Value": "Name1"}, {"Key": "tag1", "Value": "tag1valuea"}]},
{"field1":"2", "field2":"y", "Tags":[{"Key": "Name", "Value": "Name2"}]},
{"field1":"3", "field2":"z", "Tags":[{"Key": "tag2", "Value": "tag2valueb"}]}
]
```

The output I want is:

```
1 x name1
2 y name2
3 z
```

I have tried:

```
jq -r '.[] | .field1 + " " + .field2 + " " + (.Tags[] | select(.Key == "Name") .Value)'
1 x Name1
2 y Name2
```

But, as you can see, it drops the 3rd entry because it doesn't have a "Key" that is set to "Name".

Then I tried:

```
jq -r '.[] | .field1 + " " + .field2 + " " + (.Tags[] | if(.Key == "Name") then .Value else null end)'
1 x Name1
1 x
2 y Name2
3 z
```

You can see I ended up with two entries for the first object because it has an extra element in the array that I don't care about.

I have tried numerous permutations of the above two options all to no avail. I'm hoping someone has a clever way to get jq to not "empty" the item if it doesn't have key I am select'ing and/or repeat when there are items in the array I don't want to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine there are lots of ways to do this, and some probably better, but here's a `jq` filter that does it (using the `--raw-output` option).

```
.[]
| [.field1, .field2, (.Tags[]|select(.Key == "Name").Value)]
| join(" ")
```

Example output:

```
1 x Name1
2 y Name2
3 z
```

Try it on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/7A5aooFmOXT).

If `"Tags"` includes multiple `.Key == "Name"` objects, each `"Value"` is appended on the same line, like:

```
1 x Name1 AnotherName
2 y Name2
3 z
```

Try this on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/t3WeLDoJUqS).

Comment: Okay, so the what I was missing was using a comma to make each field separate, then turning each "object" into an item in an array, then using join to break the array back up. Cool!

Answer (score 1):

What if the `.Tags` array contains more than just one match? Say, there was a third item `{"Key": "Name", "Value": "AnotherName"}` in the `.Tags` array of the first ("1 x") record. Would you then prefer as output one combined line like `1 x Name1 AnotherName`, or rather two separate lines like `1 x Name1` and `1 x AnotherName`? Anyway, here's both variants using [string interpolation](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#string-interpolation), and showing outputs based on the extended input with the one added match mentioned above.

Combined lines ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/SKj2cnd70tQ)):

```bash
.[] | (.Tags | map(select(.Key == "Name").Value)) as $m
| "\(.field1) \(.field2) \($m | join(" "))"
```

```
1 x Name1 AnotherName
2 y Name2
3 z
```

Separate lines ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/LPRICfk0QXU)):

```bash
.[] | (.Tags | map(select(.Key == "Name").Value)) as $m
| "\(.field1) \(.field2) \($m[] // "")"
```

```
1 x Name1
1 x AnotherName
2 y Name2
3 z
```

Comment: Okay, this is an interesting way to approach it. I certainly didn't know about how to use the "as $var". As far as duplicates, that shouldn't happen, but if it did, I would likely use the first option. Thanks!

Comment: @kcantrel If you don't expect duplicates, you could actually use that knowledge for optimization by just taking the `first` match, and ignore subsequent checking: `.[] | "\(.field1) \(.field2) \(first(.Tags[] | select(.Key == "Name").Value) // "")"` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/g4nyDF96Phx)